# Android HttpURLConnection uses SSL connection when usesCleartextTraffic is set to true and throws SSL handshake time out exception

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, sslhandshakeexception

I am building an Android app and need to use HttpURLConnection to call a local web service. The URL is http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/webservice/movies/1. It gives correct response using Postman.
However, in Android Studio, I cannot get the connection working. I've added Internet permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, and already set       `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest file. But when I test the following method, it throws SSL handshake timed out exception. Why it still tries to use an SSL connection when the usersCleartextTraffic is set to true? How should I workaround to fix this?

```
public static ArrayList<MovieViewModel> GetTop5Movies(int personId) {
        ArrayList<MovieViewModel> movieList = new ArrayList<MovieViewModel>();
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String textResult = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(BaseURL.GET_TOP5_MOVIES_URL + personId);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            //It throws expection when it gets to the following line
            Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
            while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
                textResult += inStream.nextLine();
            }
            Log.i("Movies", textResult);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(textResult);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                movieList.add(new MovieViewModel(jsonObject.getString("Name"), jsonObject.getString("ReleaseDate"), jsonObject.getInt("RatingScore")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return movieList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL is for HTTPS not for HTTP. Why it is giving this? will tell you more if you post the logs.
Please post the manifest.xml too.